# How to capture packets at the "DSL side"?

Tags: internet, modem, sniffing, wan, packet

https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/23522/capture-packets-from-my-broadband-modem

It is written here that capturing packets passing through the modem at DSL level, would only be possible with very expensive hardware, I would like to know the necessary hardware in question.

Comment: When we close a question as off topic, posting another one asking the same question just angers those that can help.  I refer to your previous question https://superuser.com/questions/1610238/which-modem-firmware-would-allow-you-to-see-all-packets-in-transit

Comment: Also, lots of things have been written that are false.  The statement that you need expensive hardware to capture packets passing through a modem at a DSL level is both nonsensical and false.   It nonsensical because in its strict sense a modem does not know of packets, only of analog signals, bits and bytes.  At the abstracted level sometimes wrongly called a modem - you are looking at data packets which can be read through the OS/interface/driver.  As per my previous answer this is exposed in cheapish linux based routers with virtual interfaces which can be accessed via pcap clients...

Comment: One such client is tcpdump.  Another is wireshark.    And however you phrase it, asking the name of hardware which will do a specific task is a shopping recommendation.  Which leads us back to you still being off topic.  Also, the link you referred to is 7 years old, and I am fairly certain you misinterpreted the answer.

Comment: If you really have to get the data on the DSL port (rather then the PPP level), dd-wrt likely won't help as dd-wrt does not really support DSL.  I **believe** ASUS routers like the DSL-AC68U run a version of wrt which will let you access libpcap on dsl interfaces, but I've always mated a dedicated DSL "modem" with an ethernet router - and I just sniff the traffic on the WAN interface of the router.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which modem firmware would allow you to see all packets in transit](https://superuser.com/questions/1610238/which-modem-firmware-would-allow-you-to-see-all-packets-in-transit)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture data that my ADSL modem send](https://superuser.com/questions/490797/capture-data-that-my-adsl-modem-send)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of product you're looking for is called a `DSL protocol analyzer`. Plug that term into your favorite search engine.

There have been many flavors of DSL over the years, so it would probably help to specify which flavor(s) of DSL you want to be sure it can sniff. So maybe search for something like `VDSL2 protocol analyzer` or `ADSL2+ protocol analyzer`.

For any given digital communication technology that's still in use, someone makes a protocol analyzer. But they're niche products priced for  companies that create hardware products that use that technology.

Sometimes if you search deep enough into various hobbyist/hacker/geek forums for whatever digital communication technology you're interested in, you may discover that someone found a way to modify a cheap consumer product to act as a protocol analyzer (sniffer) for that technology. So maybe somewhere you can find someone who knows a particular model of DSL modem that you can load something like OpenWrt on and have a cheap DSL protocol analyzer (as long as you only care about the flavors of DSL that that particular model of modem supports). SuperUser is a bit too "generalist" to attract much of an audience of DSL geeks though, so asking around here could be a waste of time.

Comment: Do you know of a VDSL2 protocol analyzer that you could recommend? And thank you for the name of the device.